# why unit test project dll's are not being copied to solutions output folder using tfs quebuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, build-process, vs-unit-testing-framework

Unit test project dll's in my solution is not being copied to solution output folder on build. I tried to add fake reference of unit test project in other project references so that msbuild will pick up the unit test dll to output folder. But it didn't work. Please suggest if any alternative.

Comment: Normally I would say that the TFS-builds targets the main project and includes all that is needed for it to run. Im guessing that the unit test project is not needed for your application to run? If so, then why would you want those .dll's in the output? If your mainproject were to reference the Unit test project then the .dll's for that project should be included..

Comment: @Hyperdingo: Thanks for your reply. Actually we want unit tests to be executed during TFS-Builds, so in order to achieve this we want Bind the Unit Test project to the solution file.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use the old XAML build or the new build system?

Comment: version not sure.. but yes we are using XAML build.

Comment: Did you build a single project or the solution? Have you configured your solution to build all projects including unit test project?

Comment: Yes I have build the solution and also its configured to build unit test project too....

Comment: Did all other projects have been copied to output folder? Could you share your build log and output structure?

Comment: Are you able to get output of Unit test project when build locally with MSBuild?

Comment: Sorry couldn't share the logs due to internal security concerns ....all other projects have been copied to output folder and I am able to get output of unit test project when build locally.

Comment: OK..Can you check your XAML build log to see whether the dlls have been generated? Have you tried to build the Unit Test project with MSbuild locally on your build agent machine? If you build your solution with MSbuild locally on your build agent machine, can you get correct output?

Comment: I verified the build log and see that all the dll's are generated except unit test project dll. It seems its not even selected for the build by the solution. I don't have access to build solution on build agent machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to our chat, the root cause why the Unit Test's dlls won't copy to output folder is that the Unit Test Project doesn't build at all. Please check the solution configuration to see whether the project has been selected under the correct configuration. For example, if you choose Debug configuration in Build definition, you need to make sure the Unit Test project has been selected under Debug configuration.

[image]

Comment: I checked solution configuration and see that unit test project is selected under release configuration and also unit test project has been  set as release configuration.

Comment: Did you check which configuration used in your build log?

Comment: trying to build the solution from command prompt using msbuild.exe , below comments is getting displayed "The project "Repository.UnitTest" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".

Comment: Did you select Release under Active solution configuration, Any CPU under Active solution platform?

Comment: No..Selected Debug under active solution config and Any CPU under active solution platform. But unit project selected release and any CPU. In build definitions under process->configuration build is selected as AnyCPU| Release.

Comment: Try to select Release under Active solution configuration to modify Solution-wide Build Configurations.

Comment: I tried to build the solution in debug configuration and see that unit test proj dll is getting in output folder. But its not getting generated in the release mode. Other proj in the solution are building fine in both configurations.

Comment: Now your issue is proved not related to TFS, but your project setting. When you select Release under Active solution configuration, do you select the checkbox of Build for the unit test?

Comment: Yes I do select the checkbox of build for the unit test.

Comment: all the dlls are present when I run the solution locally (in active debug configuration), but when I queue up a build on the TFS build server, it is missing unit test proj dll files. Any ideas?

Comment: @AnandOoty As far as I remember, if you have reference but don't really use any code from referenced dll it will not be copied to output folder in  Release build. This was your issue here I guess.